# Return the bin of a certain value after splitting into Pandas bins after CUT or value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-fitting

Say I split my frame using `df.value_counts(bins=10)`
this is how it looks

```
Values_mean
(53.649, 90.21]                  5127
(35.369, 53.649]                 4285
(90.21, 108.49]                  3559
(108.49, 126.77]                 2579
(866.77, 935.05]                 1526
(199.891, 218.171]               1304
(218.171, 251.451]                506
(-1.46699, 17.089]                478
(251.451, 284.732]                 30
(284.732, 343.012]                  7
Name: Values_mean, dtype: int64
```

now I want to find out where the value : **newVal=38.54**
would fit and in which percentile of data is it .

example : The CUMSUM of these values = 19401
`newVal=38.54` will belong to the **Bin** :

```
(35.369, 53.649]                 4285
```

so it means 4285/19401 where it belongs to **0.2208** of the data.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to sort the index then use the `right` attribute to get at the right hand side of the intervals.  Then use `searchsorted` to find where the search value fits in.  Use that information to figure out the count value.

```
def ptile(x, s):
    total = s.sum()
    s = s.sort_index()
    i = s.index.right.searchsorted(x)
    return s.iloc[i] / total

ptile(38.54, s)

0.2208649038709345
```

Comment: Worked Like a charm , Thanks ;)